# Compass Sprite Generation while referencing a CDN

Tags: sass, cdn, sprite, compass

I'm trying to Compass's sprite generation to serve images for IE7. I want to serve the sprite image file from my CDN, so I need to output a different url that is supplied by the sprite_url helper. The sprite_url helper outputs:

```
url('//web/images/icons/fallback/sprites-s0b478f635b.png')
```

I want it to output:

```
url('//images.[DOMAIN].com/images/icons/fallback/sprites-s0b478f635b.png')
```

It would be great if I could find a way to output the path relative to my images directory, or even just the file name of the generated sprite image.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Needed to change the http_generated_images_path constant in my config.rb file. I changed it to read:

```
http_generated_images_path = "//images.[DOMAIN].com//images"
```

Then I was able to output the correct url like this:

```
$icons: sprite-map("icons/fallback/sprites/*.png");

%sprite {
    background-image: sprite-url($icons);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```